# to display the entered webstorage values inside the div tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

- I am trying to get the form values and display the values using html5 local storage
- I have written html and js code
- but I am not sure how to display the entered webstorage values inside the div tag

  **display form values---first item**
- can you tell me how to fix it..
- providing my code below
- i have put in the fiddle too

https://jsfiddle.net/r977y9zb/10/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  init();
});


function init() {
  if (localStorage["name"]) {
    $('#name').val(localStorage["name"]);
  }
  if (localStorage["email"]) {
    $('#email').val(localStorage["email"]);
  }
  if (localStorage["message"]) {
    $('#message').val(localStorage["message"]);
  }

  $('.stored').keyup(function() {
    localStorage[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
  });

  $('#localStorageTest').submit(function() {
    localStorage.clear();
  });
}
```

Comment: Are you setting the values into the local storage? Also, to get values I think you need to use either `localStorage.getItem("name");` or `loacalStorage.name`

Comment: @ZachL yes i am setting in local storage....can you update in my fiddle its confusing :(

Comment: The answer that Chris provided looks promising. You should try it.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some helper functions that might help you:

```
function setLocal(key, value) {
    localStorage.setItem(key, value);
}

function getLocal(key) {
    return localStorage.getItem(key);
}

function getAllLocal() {
    var tmp_obj = {};
    for(var key in localStorage)
        tmp_obj[key] = localStorage.getItem(key);
    return tmp_obj;
}
```

Usage:

```
setLocal('test_message', 'Hello World!');
var test_message = getLocal('test_message');
console.log(test_message); //Hello World!
```

Comment: thanks for your reply...can you update in my fiddle its confusing https://jsfiddle.net/r977y9zb/10/